# Would a solution with a hydronium concentration of 1e-10 be basic?

Tags: acid-base

So obviously the pH of the solution would be 10, which is basic on the scale. But isn't adding hydronium ions to a neutral solution that is water fundamentally acidic.

Or is it that water itself has a concentration of 1e-7 hydronium ions at any given point making any addition of hydronium ions tip the scale to acidic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the pH of a highly dilute solution of HCl](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35559/calculating-the-ph-of-a-highly-dilute-solution-of-hcl)

Comment: Are you asking about a solution which *actually* has $\ce{[H+]} = \pu{10^{-10} mol dm^{-3}}$, or are you asking about one where $\pu{10^{-10} mol dm^{-3}}$ of $\ce{H+}$ has been *added to water*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, we have to take account of the concentration of hydronium ion released from water. 
Water releases 10<sup>-7</sup> ions and the other substance used in the given problem produces 10<sup>-10</sup> H<sup>+</sup> ions. So total concentration is 10<sup>-7</sup> + 10<sup>-10</sup>. 
Taking negative log of the stuffs, we get the result pH = 6.999956 
The result shows that since the substance is very dilute, it hardly could make a major change in the pH. But never the less, keeping true to its nature, it made the solution only a slightly acidic (<7).
Remember, it's never possible to create a basic solution by just adding H<sup>+</sup> ions to water..!